# Why doesn't the dropdown-menu appear in Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The following codes work perfectly in Google Chrome or other browsers. But when tested with a safari on an iPhone, the bottom dropdown menu doesn't appear. But when I click on the screen it goes to the menu. The menu is operational but nothing appears on the screen. What is the reason of this? This appears when I add **position: fixed** to the menu. But I don't want it fixed on the screen. Any help, I'd appreciate it.

```css
   .navbar-nav {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .nav>li {
        position: initial;
        display: block;
        transition: all 0.6s ease;
    }
    #menu div.dropdown-menu {
        margin-left: 0 !important;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        background-color: #FFF;
        border: none;
        overflow-y: auto;
        border-radius: 0px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .dropdown_mobile {
        background: #FFF;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 40px;
        display: inline-table;
        align-items: center;
        transition: all 0.6s ease;
    }
    #menu .dropdown-inner {
        display: flex;
    }
    #menu div.dropdown-inner > ul.list-unstyled {
        display: flex;
    }
    #menu .dropdown-inner li {
        margin: 5px;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    #menu .dropdown-inner a {
        font-family: Century Gothic, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 600;
        color: #FFF;
    }
```

```html
    <li class="dropdown open">
              <a href="http://localhost/albigelsin/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=20" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">Fruits</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" style="">
                  <div class="dropdown_mobile">
                      <div class="dropdown-inner">                     <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                                <li><a href="http://localhost/albigelsin/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=20_26">Apple</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="http://localhost/albigelsin/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=20_27">Banana</a></li>
                                              </ul>
                                          </div>      
                  </div>
              </div>
            </li>
```

BOTTOM DROPDOWN MENU WORKS ON GOOGLE CHROME
[image]

BOTTOM DROPDOWN MENU DOESN'T WORK ON SAFARI (iPHONES)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the size of the drop-down menu. This problem can be solved by adding a **height or margin-bottom**. I changed my css files below and it works fine now. If the size of the **top menu is 70px**, for example, the pop-up **menu is 120px** when opened. However, since the size of the **menu is 70px**, the drop-down menu does not appear in the safari. I solved this by adding **margin-bottom: 70px** and pinned a ***top** to the drop-down menu.

> CSS;

```
#menu div.dropdown-menu {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: none;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border-radius: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 80px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
}
.navbar-nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
    margin-top: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(254, 202, 56) 0%, rgb(245, 130, 32) 51%, rgb(250, 69, 3) 100%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems Safari doesn't support well when `transition-property` is `all`.

Also, `-webkit-transition` should be added for better Safari support.

Try to change this:

```
.nav>li {
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
.dropdown_mobile {
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
```

To this:

```
.nav>li {
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease;
}
.dropdown_mobile {
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried, but it didn't work. Do you have any ideas?